How to auto-increment a composite key as a calculated field?
How is it possible to auto-increment a composite key (string text) in Excel while satisfying two logical conditions?
I am trying to construct a calculated field [transaction_id] by satisfying two logical && statements so if each previous value for the logical statements remain the same then the current value of the key stays the same, but if one of the logical statements changes, then the key should increment.
The key is dependent on a [date] column and a [salesperson] column.

So what's the question (what logic)? And what's your try and what does it do compared to what you expect it to do?
